# How to not evaluate alert expression(Expr) when there is no data in Prometheus metric

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, promql

I'm trying to raise alert on metric(metric_test). Evaluation interval is every 5mints.

Issue:

Suppose, At time(T1) alert is fired and prometheus scrapes metric at time(t3) but there is no metric with name metric_test at target during that time, prometheus will update as no data as shown below.
In Prometheus GUI -> Graph, when you query for metric like below , it is showing no data.

Metric_test

no data

at time(t5) evaluation of alerts happens, due to "no data" it is marking alerts as resolve. I don't want evaluation to be happen when there is no data .

How can we avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

When I understand you correctly, your metrics appear and disappear over the time? This might not be the best idea. But you can use "..._over_time" functions to aggregate metrics that are currently not there.

(by the way, scraping and evaluating expressions every 5 mins might be very slow. if you increas the frequency, you can evaluate the metrics when they are there, and you also raise alerts faster)